# Teams "Recently Active Questions" only shows ask date

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, homepage

With the introduction of the new question list view, this is what I see on my [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/) in Teams (cropped):

[image: asked 2 days ago, asked Aug 19 '20]

- It always shows "asked". You can't tell if the activity was because of an answer or an edit. If it was already on the list, you can't tell if it was edited since then.
- The name of who created/bumped it was removed. It shows the same default profile image for every post now which doesn't help anyone.

Both of these problems are exclusive to Teams. Can they be fixed? I now need to click several times to see this information, since I like to stay on the "newest" tab inside of Teams (`https://stackoverflow.com/c/[team]/questions?tab=Newest`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently "asked" instead of modified/answered was something that was [fixed on the rest of the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375468/323179) hours before I asked. Now Teams looks the same too, even showing profile images.